# Interface implemented twice "types may unify"; why does this workaround work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface-implementation

I've run into a compiler error when attempting to implement an interface twice for the same class like so:

```
public class Mapper<T1, T2> : IMapper<T1, T2>, IMapper<T2, T1>
{
   /* implementation for IMapper<T1, T2> here.  */

   /* implementation for IMapper<T2, T1> here.  */
}
```

The error:

> 'Mapper' cannot implement both 'IMapper' and 'IMapper' because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions.

Why does this workaround work? I'm wondering if I've solved the problem or just tricked the compiler.

```
public class Mapper<T1, T2> : MapperBase<T1, T2>, IMapper<T1, T2>
{
    /* implementation for IMapper<T1, T2> here. */
}

public class MapperBase<T1, T2> : IMapper<T2, T1>
{
    /* implementation for IMapper<T2, T1> here. */
}
```

**EDIT**: I've updated `MyClass`, `MyClassBase`, and `IMyInterface` to `Mapper`, `MapperBase`, and `IMapper` to represent a more real-world scenario where this issue may present itself.

Comment: does it compile without implementing the methods of interface in MyClass? if so, you have your answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider this implementation:

```
public class MyClass<T1, T2> : IMyInterface<T1, T2>, IMyInterface<T2, T1>
{
   /* implementation for IMyInterface<T1, T2> here.  */

   /* implementation for IMyInterface<T2, T1> here.  */
}
```

What does `MyClass<int, int>` implement? It implements `IMyInterface<int, int>` twice, because `IMyInterface<T1, T2>` and `IMyInterface<T2, T1>` unify when `T1` and `T2` are equal. That's why implementing both `IMyInterface<T1, T2>` and `IMyInterface<T2, T1>` on the same class is disallowed. The same reasoning would apply if you tried to implement, for example, `IMyInterface<int, T1>` and `IMyInterface<T2, double>`: the type expressions unify for `T1 = double, T2 = int`.

Consider this implementation:

```
public class MyClass<T1, T2> : MyClassBase<T1, T2>, IMyInterface<T1, T2>
{
    /* implementation for IMyInterface<T1, T2> here. */
}

public class MyClassBase<T1, T2> : IMyInterface<T2, T1>
{
    /* implementation for IMyInterface<T2, T1> here. */
}
```

What you've done is place a priority on `IMyInterface<T1, T2>` over `IMyInterface<T2, T1>`. In the event that `T1` and `T2` are equal and you have an instance of `MyClass<T1, T2>`, the `IMyInterface<T1, T2>` implementation will be selected.  If you have an instance of `MyBaseClass<T1, T2>`, the `IMyInterface<T2, T1>` implementation will be selected.

Here's a toy program that shows you the behaviors. In particular notice the behavior of `a_as_i.M(0, 1)` and `a_as_b.M(0, 1)`. If you were to implement `I<T2, T1>` explicitly on `B<T1, T2>` (by prefixing the method name with `I<T2, T1>.`), it would be impossible to call it using compile-time syntax. Reflection would be necessary.

```
interface I<T1, T2>
{
    void M(T1 x, T2 y);
}

class A<T1, T2> : B<T1, T2>, I<T1, T2>
{
    public void M(T1 x, T2 y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: M({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }
}

class B<T1, T2> : I<T2, T1>
{
    public void M(T2 x, T1 y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B: M({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Outputs "A: M(0, 1)"
        var a = new A<int, int>();
        a.M(0, 1);

        //Outputs "B: M(0, 1)"
        var b = new B<int, int>();
        b.M(0, 1);

        //Outputs "A: M(0, 1)" because I<T1, T2>
        //takes precedence over I<T2, T1>
        var a_as_i = a as I<int, int>;
        a_as_i.M(0, 1);

        //Outputs "B: M(0, 1)" despite being called on an instance of A
        var a_as_b = a as B<int, int>;
        a_as_b.M(0, 1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would consider the answer better if you added example methods that show the priority created by second example.

Comment: My intuition tells me that anything that implements Foo<T1,T2> and Foo<T2,T1> should have the methods behave symmetrically when T1 = T2, (and thus the choice of method is irrelivant). But I  guess in general there's no reason why that *must* be. So this error is just to avoid any possibility of "undefined behavior"?

Comment: @AlexisBeingessner I would suggest avoiding this particular pattern unless you can explain why it makes sense to use it. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields I totally I agree. I can't fathom a good use-case for this pattern (hence why I'm especially confused that this is even identified as a problem). Maybe if you've been coded into a corner by others and have to do some serious hacking. This is madness all the way down as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AlexisBeingessner and TimothyShields, I've updated the class and interface names in my question to the names I was actually using when I ran into the issue.  The intent behind the Mapper class design was to have a two way mapping (to be used in both read and write operations) between my "domain" objects and "database" objects.

Comment: @TimothyShields I dont see any madness. A very common scenario is trying to implement standard interfaces such as `IEnumerable<T>` for more than one type. Random examples: `class Family : IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<Pet>`, `class Room : IEnumerable<Door>, IEnumerable<Window>`. There are other interfaces for which it makes similar sense too.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tricked the compiler, you've made it so that you won't have competing function definitions.  Assume your interface has the function `string Convert(T1 t1, T2 t2)`.  With your first (illegal) code, if you did `MyClass<string, string>`, you would have 2 instances of the same function.  With your base class, those 2 instances will be in `MyClassBase` and `MyClass`, so the one in `MyClass` will HIDE the other one, instead of conflict with that.  Whether that works or not is up to you, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is caused by unability of the compiler to reveal which of the implemented methods should be invoked if one of the `T1` or `T2` types is descendant of another (or is the same type).
Imagine what should it do if you instantiate the class `MyClass<int, int>`.